# What does "with a balcony same size as the room" mean?

Tags: meaning

> I didn't like the tiny size of the room we were given with a balcony
>   same size as the room.

What does this sentence mean? Does it mean:

> I didn't like the tiny size of the room that we had. The room's size was the same as that of a balcony.

or

> I didn't like the tiny size of the room we had. The room had a balcony, and the balcony's size was the same as that of the room.

I think the latter one is correct, but I want to be sure.

I read this somewhere from a review website. It's not clear where I read it because it's been a while. I didn't understand it clearly then, so I wrote it down and I'm asking about its meaning now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given sentence:

> I didn't like the tiny size of the room we were given with a balcony same size as the room.

is a bit unclear.  I think it should have been written as:

> I didn't like the tiny size of the room we were given, with a balcony **the** same size as the room.

This would mean that the room had a balcony, and the balcony was the same size as the room itself, presumably a rather small size, sine the speaker called it "tiny". Since there is no standard size for a balcony -- they are often small, but can be large in some cases -- comparing the room's size to that of a purely hypothetical balcony, one that does not actually exist, doesn't make much sense. Besides if that were the intent, it would be written more like:

> > I didn't like the tiny size of the room we were given; it was no bigger than a balcony.

That would make the comparison to a generic balcony clearer.

So I think your second meaning is correct.